# Creating Different Colours From A Pulsed Monochromatic Light Source

Tags: visible-light, laser, dispersion, fiber-optics

I am currently learning about fibre optic communications, which I understand use pulsed laser sources to generate a "bitstream" to send through the fibre using some form of pulse width modulation, either RZ (return to zero) or NRZ (not return to zero).

The text I am working with discusses the spectral content of such a pulsed signal, which makes sense to me, given that we can decompose such an on-off wave into the sums of many sine and cosine waves. It also mentions that chromatic dispersion will then affect those pulses, because the propagation speed is frequency dependent.

My question is if we are modeling this signal as being made up of a number of different spectral components, which are affected by chromatic dispersion, could you generate a pulsed signal using a monochromatic source, feed it through something like a prism, and get out multiple different wavelengths of light (with periodically varying intensities I would guess)? To restate in case that isn't clear, could a pulsed monochromatic light source be used to construct other colour light?

Comment: Google "optical comb generator"

Comment: ‘Short pulse’ and monochromatic are incompatible.

Comment: @JonCuster By monochromatic I meant that the source is a laser with a defined output wavelength; your comment gets at my central confusion. How does a laser, which produces a single wavelength end up creating all these other wavelengths of light simply by virtue of being periodically pulsed?

Comment: A short pulsed laser generates a broad range of wavelengths, else it can’t be short. You are on the right track with the Fourier transform from time to frequency domain. Just stop thinking that lasers are tightly monochromatic. Some (cw) are really close. Others aren’t.